# Is Winforms + mysql + asp.net going to be enough for a C# database-app with remote access?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, wpf, winforms

I'm trying to build software for property management, which includes full accounting support, document storage, client data handling and mail merge functionality.

I want to work with the smallest arsenal of tools that I'll need for the job - the simpler the better! It won't be graphics-intensive and support for multimedia is not required, but I would really like remote access.

95% of usage will be by property managers through their local desktop installations.

5% will be by owners, who want to check their account balance online, and change their personal details in the DB. There can be no installation for this.

Will asp.net suffice for this 5% remote access?

I only have a small amount of experience with winforms, and could learn asp.net if that's what I need for the remote access. My question is: Will this be enough for my objectives, or am I going to kick myself halfway through for not using something else? (WPF, Silverlight etc)

Thank you. I did ask this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628436/c-sharp-property-management-database-software-should-i-use-wpf-winforms-or-si earlier but didn't receive satisfactory results, and have changed my question slightly.

**EDIT:**
By data processing I mean running functions like "charge all 2,000 owners in the system a management fee increase of 5%" or "process all creditor payments into a batch banking file".

Comment: Is it a requirement to install the application? If not you could just use ASP.Net + MySQL to do the job.

Comment: There will need to be a lot of data processing, and all similar software I've seen has been installed. I'm also reluctant to make it web-dependent, as I believe ASP.Net is?

Comment: When you say data processing what type of data are you talking about? Excel? Does all users have VPN access? If so you could host your web application within your network as an intranet application instead of an internet application.

Comment: I don't mean excel, I mean data stored in the database. 
Am I right to say that if I went the ASP.Net + MySQL route, that the "look and feel" of the program would then have to be written in HTML & CSS? Is ASP.Net just for functionality?

Comment: You don't need to worry about data processing as long as you write your business logic/ Data model correctly. Yes, ASP.Net returns HTML. I believe you are new to Asp.net. It's much similar to Winforms design (I mean only UI design), but with HTML controls. you could drag and drop controls to pages you design.

Comment: Yes I am brand new to ASP.Net. My concerns with a web app are mainly that it's unnecessary 95% of the time. I couldn't imagine using a web version of MS Access - it just seems that DB apps need to be more concrete (ie desktop). It's probably a personal preference, but can it be done with winforms/WPF?

Comment: Oh, the other issue I had with a web app is local device access to printers, scanners etc - that is really important and I've heard it can be a challenge for a web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't go for WinForms and Silverlight,
WPF is much more useful than WinForms
likewise ASP.net or ASP.net MVC based applications are more useful than Silverlight based web applications. And if you are planning to go for a web based solution, choose ASP.net MVC.

Now, concerning your decision to choose between desktop and web based solutions, I would personally suggest to go for a web based solution if there is no specific requirement which holds you going online. Also Google on pros and cons of web and desktop applications and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072904/advantages-of-web-applications-over-desktop-applications).

And if you find out that a desktop application suits you, then develop it in WPF not in WinForms.

:)